# Are duplicate directives in php.ini going to cause an issue?

Tags: php

I sent a request to ops today to update some php.ini directives, and found out that he merely appended them to the end of the file.  My google search didn't really come up with any info on whether this is a problem or not to have duplicates in there and how they would be parsed.  Obviously, it can cause confusion, but, I would have a stronger argument if I knew if this was acceptable or not.

Any input?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The last mentioned value takes precedence.

```
memory_limit = 32M

... # more directives

memory_limit = 128M

<EOF>
```

Makes the `memory_limit` be 128M.

Answer (score 4):

It is usually not a crisis if something is declared twice. The normal behaviour would then be to use the last value parsed.